# phpMyAdmin is giving me error on login to remote.. #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, selinux

I am trying to setup phpMyAdmin to use with a remote MySQL databases on Scientific Linux release 6.2.

If I use the mysql command line to connect to the remote database it works great but if I use mysqladmin I am getting "#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server".

I have found if I do a:

**setenforce 0**

It will work from myphpadmin to my remote database but once I reboot or set Scientific Linux setenforce back to one it stops working again..

I know setenforce 0 is not the right thing to do but can someone please give me details steps on how to get this working the right way... thanks  I am new to Scientific Linux  and been having some issues.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working just now... All I had to do was **setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1** and now its working